# Having trouble removing duplicates in List<class>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, duplicates, ienumerable

I have a class and list:

```
    public class className
    {
        public string firstParam { get; set; }
        public string secondParam { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<className> listName = new List<className>();
```

The list includes (for example):

```
Apple    Banana
Corn     Celery
Corn     Celery
Corn     Grapes
Raisins  Pork
```

I am trying to edit the list (or create a new list) to get:

```
Apple    Banana
Corn     Celery
Corn     Grapes
Raisins  Pork
```

I have tried:

```
var listNoDupes = listName.Distinct();
```

And:

```
IEnumerable<className> listNoDupes = listName.Distinct();
```

But both return the list in the same condition as before, with duplicates.

Comment: How do the CLR know what does 'distinct' mean to you for `className` objects?

Comment: how do you know what to replace the duplicate one with ?

Comment: Is the input list always ordered as in your example, or could it be in a completely random order?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override/implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`,  right now you are listing distinct instances and they are correctly ALL distinct/unique from each other.

Comment: @user2340818 https://www.google.com/search?q=GetHashCode&oq=GetHashCode&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65l2.3199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: It's not a particularly good design to have the identity of the object be mutable properties of that object.

Comment: then he should make his properties read only, and my answer is technically correct and the simplest answer.

Comment: @TMcKeown It's most certainly not the simplest.  Habib's is absolutely simpler.  It's not trivial to learn how to implement hash codes of composite objects in a manor that is both correct and results in reasonably well distributed hashes.

Comment: For that single example of course, but it's a hack.  Nothing wrong with a hack, if there is a need to compare these object else where then you are wrong with a capital W Servy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is the identity of the objects is not what you think. Your intuition is telling you that the identity is the combination of `firstParam` and `secondParam`. What truly is happening is each distinct instance of `className` has its own identity that does not rely on the implementation of the object. You will need to override the methods provided via `System.Object`, mainly `Equals` and `GetHashCode` although you might get away with not overriding `GetHashCode` (this will be needed for hash sets to work properly.)

Answer (score 1):

If your class only contains those two fields then instead of implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` You can also do:

```
var listNoDupes = listName.GroupBy(r => new { r.firstParam, r.secondParam })
                        .Select(grp => grp.First())
                        .ToList();
```

Or you can get an `IEnumerable<T>` back like:

```
IEnumerable<className> listNoDupes = 
                       listName
                           .GroupBy(r => new { r.firstParam, r.secondParam })
                           .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

The code above would group on the properties `firstParam` and `secondParam`, later `grp.First` would return you a single item from the group and you will end up a single item from each group, *(no duplicates)*

Comment: Although you should remember to consider the size of the data set.

Comment: @ChaosPandion In what way?

Comment: Is this advantageous over Equals and GetHashCode? My class does in fact only contain those two fields.

Comment: can you explain a little pleaae  ``.Select(grp => grp.First())``

Comment: @Servy - This method will have a considerable amount of temporary objects created.

Comment: the LINQ query is grouping by first and second param, then selecting the first item in each group.  results in a unique list.  You should implement the gethashcode if you ever want to do any other logic/comparisons without the linq hack

Comment: @ChaosPandion It creates one extra item for each item in the list yes, but very short lived objects have a very low overhead.  Were the items to be long lived, or the size of the collection be so large that it can fit into memory once, but not twice, then it could potentially be an issue, yes.  The list would need to be *very* large for that to be the case though, making it a situation most people aren't going to be in.

Comment: @user2340818, I would personally choose any, if these are the only two properties in your class and your List size is not that large ^^, then use this LINQ based method. It is simple and would work. Also implementing Equals and GetHashCode shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @Servy - I count at lease 3 new objects per item (anonymous object, `IGrouping`, `IEnumerable` that is associated with the `IGrouping`). We also have to consider what is happening behind the scenes which is most likely pretty good performance but not something you can ignore for large data sets.

Comment: @ChaosPandion You have one anonymous object per item in the set, you have one grouping per *group*, which, if there are a lot of duplicates, may well be quite a lot less than the number of items in the set.  As for the `IEnumerable`, there is only one of those.  it's constant and not dependent on the size of the collection.

Comment: @Servy - The `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable` and calling `First` will allocate an `IEnumerator` (There is actually an optimization for `IList` which `IGrouping` does not implement.) Overall my whole point was to remind people to be mindful of the costs that may not be obvious. I'm certainly not trying to say that it will perform terribly in all situations.

Comment: @ChaosPandion While `IGrouping` does not itself inherit from `IList`, the actual MS implementation of `GroupBy` returns a type that *does* implement `IList`, so the optimization you describe *is* actually performed.

Answer (score 1):

There is the third possibility - use `Distinct` method version that takes `IEqualityComparer`. Unfortunately, C# does not support creating anonymous, temporary implementations of interfaces. We can create helper class and extension:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public class LambdaEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private Func<T, T, bool> comparer;
        private Func<T, int> hash;

        public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> comparer, 
                                      Func<T, int> hash)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer;
            this.hash = hash;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return comparer(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T x)
        {
            return hash(x);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elems,
                                             Func<T, T, bool> comparer,
                                             Func<T, int> hash)
    {
        return elems.Distinct(new LambdaEqualityComparer<T>(comparer, hash));
    }
}
```

and then we can provide lambdas for `Distinct` method:

```
var filteredList = myList.Distinct((x, y) => x.firstParam == y.firstParam &&
                                             x.secondParam == y.secondParam,
                                    x => 17 * x.firstParam.GetHashCode() + x.secondParam.GetHashCode());
```

This allows you to distinct objects on single shot, without implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. If, for example, there is a single place in the project, where you are calling such `Distinct`, this is probably enough to use this extension. If, on the other hand, identity of the `className` objects is a concept that spans through many methods and classes, for sure it will be better to define simply `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: `17 * x.firstParam.GetHashCode() + x.secondParam.GetHashCode()` will cause an exception sometimes if Arithmetic Overflow/Underflow checking is enabled. OK, I guess not many people will enable it in C#, but it could happen.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, pretty much every `GetHashCode` implementation you ever write should be in an `unchecked` block for that reason, just to safeguard against being used in a project without that setting enabled, even though having an entire project be checked is rather uncommon.